# Ajax Login Validation using native EE function

Tags: ee2, ajax, validation

I'm rather new to EE, and I'm having a hard time finding some stuff in it.
I started working on a legacy site that is pure EE template and for every validation it goes to a new page.
I'm wanting to use jQuery/Ajax/EE for validation, but I can't find the function that would validate the data on submission. I also want to know what is EE using to hash the passwords so I can correctly hash before I send to the server.
If anyone can provide a link or an answer I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then you don't really need to know what function EE is using but simply submit your login form via Ajax to the URL it would normally submit to.

You might also want to look at these add-ons. Some of them cost a few dollars but they will probably cost less than the time you will spend on trying to create the same functionality.

http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=ajax+login&addon_version_support=ee2

Comment: I already did the second option (AJAX Login 1.5.5 - By Laisvunas), only to realize that it had no support for login. I thought of the first option too, but it's a big page (it's being sent to the landing page), and I would have to parse all of that content just for an error message or to maybe reload the page if success. I will have to go for something like that if I have no option, but I can bet my arm that there is a function out there that would make my life easier.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. You said you wanted to log in via Ajax. Surely the only data being sent would be the login creds and being recieved, a status message? Depending on the status message you would then redirect or refresh the page in the normal way. You wouldn't need to load the entire landing page via Ajax, just determine whether or not login was successful then perform some action.